# Same input list to two different queries in sql server using java db method

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I want to establish single connection with sql server for two different queries having same input.
Is that acheivable?
Here is my code which will establish the connection with database twice for executing queries seperately with same input.

```
   String query1="select ID_Student,Lib_Sec_Book from Library_db1  where ID_Student";

   String query2="select ID_Student,Lib_Sec_Book from Library_db2  where ID_Student";

   Map<String, String> result1=dba.dbcon(inputListMismatch,query1);
   Map<String, String> result2=dba.dbcon(inputListMismatch,query2);
```

these queries have same student IDs as input,I need to find out which ID having book from two library databases.It may mutually exclusive.

saving resultset of query1 and query2 in result1 and result2 respectively
two results need to be in single Map.
In dba method,

```
Map<String, String> result=new HashMap<String,String>();

try {
 String databaseDriver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
 Class.forName(databaseDriver);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}


try 
{
 String url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server;instance=";

 java.sql.Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection(url);

 System.out.println("Connection created");
 String sqlQuery=query+" "+getIn(list.size());

 PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);

 for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
  preparedStatement.setString(i+1, (String) list.get(i));

 ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
 ResultSetMetaData rsMeta=rs.getMetaData();
 int colcount=rsMeta.getColumnCount();
 result.put(rsMeta.getColumnName(1),rsMeta.getColumnName(2));

 while(rs.next())
 {
  result.put(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2));
 }

 rs.close();
 preparedStatement.close();
 con.close();
} 
catch (Exception e1) 
{
 e1.printStackTrace();
}
 return result;
}
```

getting input list

```
     static String getIn(int numParams) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("IN (?");
    for(int i=1; i<numParams; i++)
        builder.append(",?");
    builder.append(")");
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Now I am getting two different resultset, I want to pass two queries in a single instance.
I tried union,It is throwing "Parameter has not been set" error.
and I have also tried 'allowMultiQueries=TRUE" that is not helping.
Can you suggest better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want,but I try to give you some suggestions.

If you are looking for a solution to improve performance,use two threads to query simultaneously. Use  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html to control threads.

If you want to merge two queries into one query , try the following code to build sql.

```
String sqlQuery=query+" "+getIn(list1.size()) +" union "+ getIn(list2.size());
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);

for(int i=0; i<list1.size(); i++)
   preparedStatement.setString(i+1, (String) list.get(i));

for(int i=0; i<list2.size(); i++)
   preparedStatement.setString(list1.size()+i+1, (String) list.get(i));
```

Comment: Thank you for your input..Am getting error "Parameter #(list.size()+1) has not been set"

Comment: I have used query                                                  String sqlQuery=query1+" "+getIn(list.size())+" union "+query2+" "+getIn(list.size());

Comment: Have you tested using hard-code sql string? For example ,String sqlQuery=query+" in(?,?,?) union "+ query2 +" in(?,?,?)" and then for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
   preparedStatement.setString(list1.size()+i+1,"1");

Comment: I have tested by giving values, I got exception "Invalid parameter index #(list.size()+1).

Comment: I will do some experiments for you tomorrow. I will find one for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts .I will try to modify code to suit for checking hard coded values.Before that it worked properly for one query with input list,the problem occurs when I am using multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the following code using DB2 database ,  and I think it will work well with other dbs. Because jdbc will make sure its API's are suitable for different database .

```
    String urlRemote = "jdbc:db2://fake_ip_address:60004/fake_db_instance_name";//远程方式连接DB2的默认端口为6789
    String strJDBCRemote = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
    String userName = "fake_user";
    String password = "fake_password";
    Class.forName(strJDBCRemote);

     //连接远程时必须要有用户名和密码，否则连接时报错
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(urlRemote,userName,password);
    String sql = "select id,value  from fake_table1 where id=?  union select member_number as id,dbindx_number as value from fake_table2";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setString(1,"1");
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
      System.out.println(rs.getString(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2));  
    }
    con.close();
```

Comment: Hi Thank you..I tried the above code which throws the error "Parameter #(list.size()+1) has not been set" , for one record it is working for list it is not working  pstmt.setString(i+1,list.get(i)); this is where it is throwing error> I dont know how to rectify that Error.